# ubuntu16.04 で gitkの日本語フォントがとても汚い

Tags: git

ubuntu16.04 で gitkの日本語フォントがとても汚いです。
どうすれば設定変更できるのでしょうか？
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: git 2.14.1 の gitk にはメニューに 編集 > 設定 > フォント がありますが、古いのだと無いですか？

Comment: フォントを変更してもほとんど効果が無いですね。挙動からすると、編集＞設定＞フォントで変えられるのは、アルファベットの部分のみのように見えます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bashrcにてanaconda3/binにパスを通していたのが原因だったようです。
exportを無効にして再度試したところ、綺麗に表示されました。
とはいえanaconda3を弄りたい時にはデフォルトでパスが通っていたほうが便利です。

anaconda3/binにパスを通して同様の症状が起きるか、起きる場合はどうすれば避けられるか知っている人がいたら教えてください。

Comment: anaconda で git をインストールしていて、それに付属している gitk のフォントが汚い、ということであれば、anaconda の git は削除してしまうか、`/usr/bin/gitk` のように明示的にシステムの `gitk` を実行する手もあります。`/usr/bin/wish ${anacondaのパス}/bin/gitk` のようにして、`tcl/tk` だけシステムのものを使うこともできます。

Comment: gitkを呼ぶときに、${anacondaのパス}/bin/wishが使われて、anacondaのtcl/tkが使われてしまったようです。『.bashrcで${anacondaのパス}/binをPATHの後ろに追記することで優先度を下げ』かつ『/usr/bin/python』を削除することで、anacondaのpythonを使いたいという要望を満たしながら、システムのtcl/tkを使いgitkのフォントが綺麗に表示されることが確認できました。皆様ご回答有り難うございました。

Answer (score 3):

私も `gitk` で同じ現象が起きました。
 `wish` はシステム以外を呼んでいました。

```
$ which wish
/home/username/.pyenv/shims/wish
```

`gitk` の起動時に `/usr/bin/wish8.x` を呼ぶようにして解決しました。

```
$ sudo vi /usr/bin/gitk

### 3行目 Before
exec wish "$0" -- "$@"

### 3行目 After
exec /usr/bin/wish8.6 "$0" -- "$@"
```

ちなみに `wish8.6` を呼んでいるのは無印よりもフォントが奇麗だったからです。
ご参考まで

[image: きれいなやつ]

Comment: こちらで試したところ、　`Error in startup script: can't read "0": no such variable
    while executing
"exec /usr/bin/wish8.6 "$0" -- "$@""
    (file "/usr/bin/gitk" line 4)`　というエラーが出てしまいました。

Comment: /usr/bin/wish8.6 を /usr/bin/wish にして試してみて下さい．

Comment: tclのコメントアウトの仕方に誤りがありました。正しくコメントアウトしたらきれいなフォントで表示されました。#と\で挟む必要があるんですね。shライクに#でコメントアウトできると思いこんでしまっていました。